# Scala fold versus Play! fold

Tags: scala

Scala fold :

```
fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1
```

Play! fold :

```
fold[E, A](state: A)(f: (A, E) ⇒ A): Iteratee[E, A]
```

Appears the signature above of the Play! API fold is no longer available and I'm unable to find it's signature on versions 2.0 & 2.7. I'm attempting to understand the difference in behavior of the Scala versus Play! fold from their respective method signatures. The Scala fold returns type `A1` while Play! fold returns `Iteratee[E, A]` but what are its functional differences ?

I've searched Play! versions https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/api/scala/index.html#package & 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/index.html but I'm unable to discover

Comment: Some documentation here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Iteratees

Comment: from which class is the Play `fold`?